# MongooseIm : HOW TO USE FORM_TYPE WITH MOD_VCARD

Tags: mongoose-im

We are sending user search request from our xmpp client in the below format using FORM_TYPE.

```
<iq id=”w615o-7″ to=”search.my.server.com” type=”set”>
<query xmlns=”jabber:iq:search”>
<x xmlns=”jabber:x:data” type=”submit”>
<field var=”FORM_TYPE” type=”hidden”><value>jabber:iq:search</value></field>
<field var=”search” type=”text-single”><value>my@email.com</value></field>
<field var=”Email” type=”boolean”><value>1</value></field>
</x>
</query>
</iq>
```

But it seems mod_vcard doesnt recognize this kind of format. Im planning to change the code of the module to sort this out. However, is there an easier way to do this ?